# Vue-Cli project build problems

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vue-cli

I have a Vue project.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlZuC.png)

I want to start project with npm run serve, but project hang when start development server. It never progressing. Have any of you experienced this problem before? Can I get your advice? I deleted the node modules folder, reinstalled npm. I deleted vue-cli, reinstalled it. Still the problem is not solved. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more? Like, how did you setup the project? Node and npm version etc.

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable `DEBUG="*"` before running the project ? It might provide you with more insight about the situation. Most probably there is an error somewhere deep inside Vue-CLI or Webpack which is simply not propagated to the console/terminal.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Node version --> 18.18.0 Npm version --> 10.2.0 I did made development  in the project yesterday. There was no such problem.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I don't know what I should do. I didn't quite understand what you wanted to say. After running the npm run serve command, the project gets stuck at 51% during compilation. It's not progressing. Thats the problem. I wanted to ask if anyone has experienced the problem before and what the solutions are.

Comment: I found the cause of problem. It is related to the length of the css codes in the Tailwind css file. That's ridiculous. However, after deleting some of the css blocks, the build process was completed.

Comment: @HarunDoğan That's really strange. Are you sure, problem is related to length and not CSS code itself?

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Yes. I'm not sure if the CSS length is the real cause of the problem, but after deleting some of the css blocks and running the "npm run serve" command again, the build process was completed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.